# Javascript TypeError is not a function issue

Tags: javascript, resize, ticker

Run into a JavaScript issue that I can't understand. I'm making a JavaScript "class" that is supposed to draw some things on a canvas, and if the window gets resized, it's supposed to know how to resize the canvas on its own and fix orientation for the drawn objects.

Everything seems to work fine when I use this class from my own test html, but when I extracted my class into a separate .js file to be added as `<script src="myclass.js"></script>` for other people's usage, it starts throwing a `"TypeError: this.func02 is not a function"` error upon resize. This is annoying because this.func02 clearly is a function.

Also, there's a ticker constantly calling func03, and in the console I can clearly see logs being printed out periodically (those logs happen from func01, which is called by func03, in the exact same way that func02 calls it). Those logs keep working even after a TypeError showing up whenever I resize.

The JS:

```
function myClass() {
    this.func01 = function() {
      console.log("func1");
      //do stuff
    }
    this.func02 = function() { //<- this doesn't work ???
      this.func01();
      //and do more stuff
    }
    this.func03 = function() { //<- this works ???
      this.func01();
      //stuff
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.func02, false);
}

function useMe() {
    objectOfMyClass = new myClass();
    setInterval(tickerThatCallsFunc03ofMyClass, 50);
}
```

If anybody has any idea why this happens, please write stuff. I'm stumped on debugging this. I tried to remove all irrelevant code from my program, if you need more information post and I'll add it.

Note: the problem here isn't the keyword "this". Maybe it's part of the problem, but it's not all of it. The exact code works when it's in one file with the html, but doesn't work when it's added to the html with

Comment: Kindly provide a fiddle so that it will be helpful to debug

Comment: my actual code is several thousands of lines and uses a lot of external assets to draw images as well as createjs and jquery, I'd rather not post it on fiddle... I think the key of the problem here is maybe not the code itself but rather me using it externally wrong? the exact code works fine inside an html, but if I delete it from the html and replace with <script src="mycode.js"></script> and put everything that was originally between <script> tags in the html into mycode.js that's when the error happens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Are you sure that mycode.js is loaded before you create an object and call a function?

Comment: please add the code and/or provide a jsfiddle (create at jsfiddle.net)

Comment: how can I check if it loaded? can I apply onload to src lines somehow?

Comment: Put your other code inside:

$(function() {
 // HERE
});

( if you are using jquery )

Or put the <script src="mycode.js"></script> before the other code...

Comment: well, it *is* before the other code. it's right in the beginning of the html. it does let me instantiate an object of my class. actually I should've realized this earlier, the fact that it does means it's fully loaded. I did a console log on the object and it gives me all the attributes and functions of it.

Comment: you didn't call the function did you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is inside of a function is referencing the function not the class to save a reference to the class and use that within a function:

```
function myClass() {
    var myclass = this;
    this.func01 = function() {
          console.log("func1");
          //do stuff
    }
    this.func02 = function() { //<- this doesn't work ???
        myclass.func01(); //<- I get typeError on this call
        //and do more stuff
    }
    this.func03 = function() { //<- this works ???
        myclass.func01();
        //stuff
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.func02, false);
}

function useMe() {
    objectOfMyClass = new myClass();
    setInterval(tickerThatCallsFunc03ofMyClass, 50);
}
```

Comment: so I tried and this actually solved my problem. thanks. what I don't get is why func03 manages to call func01 if this is the case. and also why the whole thing worked before I moved it to another file...